# Build a recipe page with multiple listviews

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to construct a recipe page that contains a title and video at the top followed by some more information than three listViews for ingredients equipment and methods. I tried to put them all into a scroll view but it truncates all the listviews, it is also considered bad practice. how do I make this page scrollable and still have the three listviews?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:video="clr-namespace:SQLiteListView.FormsVideoLibrary"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SQLiteListView.Models"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:SQLiteListView.ViewModels"
             x:Class="SQLiteListView.Views.RecipePage"
             Title="{Binding Recipe.RecipeName}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Recipe.RecipeName}"
                       FontSize="50" />
                    <video:VideoPlayer HeightRequest="320" WidthRequest="220">
                        <video:VideoPlayer.Source>
                            <video:ResourceVideoSource>
                                <video:ResourceVideoSource.Path>
                                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Videos/iOSApiVideo.mp4" />
                                        <On Platform="Android" Value="ScrambledEggs.mp4" />
                                        <On Platform="UWP" Value="Videos/UWPApiVideo.mp4" />
                                    </OnPlatform>
                                </video:ResourceVideoSource.Path>
                            </video:ResourceVideoSource>
                        </video:VideoPlayer.Source>
                    </video:VideoPlayer>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
                    <Label 
                    Margin="10"
                    Text="Meal Type"
                    FontSize="Large" 
                    FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label 
                    Text="{Binding Recipe.MealType}"
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Serves" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Recipe.Serves}" 
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Preperation Time" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Recipe.PrepTime}" 
                       Margin="10"
                       Grid.Row="8"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>

                    <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Cooking Time" 
                       FontSize="Large" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Recipe.CookTime}"  
                       Margin="10"
                       FontSize="Medium"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
                    <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Equipment" 
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                    <viewmodels:NonScrollableListView ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentList}" 
                                                  x:Name="EquipmentListView" >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding EquipmentName}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </viewmodels:NonScrollableListView>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="4">
                    <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Ingredients" 
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                    <Picker Title="--Number of People--"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding PickersList}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding NumberOfPeople}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPicker}"/>


                    <viewmodels:NonScrollableListView x:Name="IngredientsListView"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientsList}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="5">
                                                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding IngredientsName}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                                <Label HorizontalOptions="End"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding Ammount}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                                <Label HorizontalOptions="End"
                                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                               Text="{Binding Units}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </viewmodels:NonScrollableListView>
                </StackLayout>


                <Label Margin="10"
                       Text="Method"
                       Grid.Row="15"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>

                <viewmodels:NonScrollableListView x:Name="MethodList" 
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding MethodList}"
                                                  Grid.Row="16">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell Height="500">
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                            <Label Text="{Binding MethodNumber}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding MethodName}"
                                               FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </viewmodels:NonScrollableListView>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a problem with listviews being scrollable all you have to do is make them un-scrollable and you can make a custom renderer for it something like this:

**Custom Listview in PCL:**

```
 public class NonScrollableListView : ListView
{

    public NonScrollableListView() : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

**Android Listview:**

```
 public class NonScrollableListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public NonScrollableListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        try
        {
            if (e == null || e.NewElement == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var lit = e.NewElement;
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var listView = this.Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
                listView.NestedScrollingEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }       

    public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
    {
        base.OnViewAdded(child);

    }


    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {

            }
            if (Element == null)
            {

            }
            base.OnDetachedFromWindow();

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        disposing = false;
        if (Element == null)
        {

        }
        if (Control == null)
        {

        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

**iOS Listview:**

```
public class NonScrollableListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public NonScrollableListViewRenderer()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
            return;

        var tableView = Control as UITableView;
        tableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        tableView.ScrollEnabled = true;

    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the ExportRenderer header on the namespace:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NonScrollableListView), typeof(NonScrollableListViewRenderer))]
```

**Update**

Saw your code a little and I realized that you are using `StackLayout` as the outermost parent to all the listview's and everything else so I would suggest that you try setting the `StackLayout` spacing to 0 and if that doesn't solve the problem then I would suggest you replace that `StackLayout` with a `Grid` and set all the RowDefinitions to Auto and try again

Comment: thanks for your reply, I don't have a problem with listviews being scrollable the issue is that I have multiple listviews in a scroll view. each of these listviews get cut short or remain too long, how do I expand a listview to show the number of items within it

Comment: See that issue happens when you have a listview that is scrollable if you have a non-scrollable listview and you set the height for it as per your need you can achieve what you are looking for

Comment: the android class doesn't recognise AppLogger

Comment: Remove that please that is my personal code sorry will remove that

Comment: so I've added the classes and built it what do I need to do next to get it to implement

Comment: Well all you have to do is replace your listview with the non-scrollable listview

Comment: I added it  <viewmodels:NonScrollableListView ItemsSource="{Binding MethodList}">. It still doesn't allow me to change the size of the view cell or the stack layout within it.

Comment: What exactly is happening when you try to do it i mean did you set the height??

Comment: yes I set the Viewcell height to 100 and nothing changed

Comment: Why don't you set the RowHeight property in listview? instead of setting ViewCell height?? Also, check updated answer

Comment: I can now increase the row height. it there a way to alter it dynamically, Like if one cell has 4 lines of information and another has only 2, the row height changes for the amount of information within each row

Comment: That is why i suggested you use Grid layout and set the height to Auto

Comment: I've changed the stack layout to a grid how do I change the row definitions

Comment: so I added                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

Comment: so it now blows the page apart, each element is far away from the other

Comment: Set the grid row spacing to zero please

Comment: I've added the RowSpacing as zero but it hasn't really worked. I have updated the code above so you can see what I have done.